# How to display two column values in a single ag-grid cell?

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I have a record of First_Name and Second_Name stored in MySql DB. Currently I am displaying it in 2 different columns of Ag-Grid. I need those data to be combined together as Name and to be displayed in Ag-Grid's single column. Please help!

I am using Vue.Js

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `valueGetter` in your columnDef like this -

```
  {
    headerName: 'Name',
    colId: 'name',
    valueGetter: function(params) {
      return params.data.First_Name + " " + params.data.Second_Name;
    },
  },
```

Example from docs [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters/#example-value-getters)

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The ans stated by Pratik is right. Maybe you can use arrow functions for valueGetter so that the code looks more concise and simplify function scoping.
{
    headerName: 'Name',
    valueGetter: params => {
      return `${params.data.First_Name} ${params.data.Second_Name}`;
    },
},